Error with SRV Host Name in Spring Boot MongoDB Configuration using .env file
I am referring to this video: Spring Boot + MongoDB | Crash Course
While storing the information about the URI in a .env file, it's giving the following error:
An SRV host name '${env.MONGO_CLUSTER}' was provided that does not contain at least three parts. It must contain a hostname, domain name and a top level domain.

All the information in the .env file is correct:
MONGO_DATABASE='movies-api-db'
MONGO_USER='LoKi'
MONGO_PASSWORD='****************'
MONGO_CLUSTER='cluster0.bubp9pu.mongodb.net'

And I have also added the dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>me.paulschwarz</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-dotenv</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>

in the pom.xml file.
My application.properties file looks like this:
spring.data.mongodb.database=${env.MONGO_DATABASE}
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://${env.MONGO_USER}:${env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@${env.MONGO_CLUSTER}

Where am I going wrong?
In the video, it's at: (0:44:48) Setting Up Environment Variables.
Things I have tried:

Verified the .env file for correct values.
Ensured that the .env file is in the root directory of the project.
Checked the environment variables by printing them out in the application.

I also tried the solution to this question, but then I got the following error:
com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Failed looking up SRV record for '_mongodb._tcp.'cluster0.bubp9pu.mongodb.net''.

and
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]

Any help would be appreciated!

I finally found the answer!
These are the points which caused it:

In the .env file I had used '' instead of "". (Some parsers or tools used to load environment variables might interpret single quotes differently or not support them at all.)

The link which I have provided for "What I have tried" is totally correct. I wasn't sure about using "" in the .env file so thought this answer was not working!


